# Can't access my wordpress multisite superaccount anymore :(

Tags: php, wordpress, account

I made a wordpress multisite with a primary site that links to two other sites. www.jimvanlent.com is the site. Unfortunately i can't access the main site anymore. When I go to the wp-admin part, I get a message that says that I do not have enough rights to access it. This is quite strange, because I only have one account and it has admin rights.

Hope you can help this poor dude :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way if you have access to database is to manually go to the `wp_users` table like this :

```
SELECT * FROM wp_users;
```

You will see allowed users.

More details about WP database [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description).

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you can login with the account, but you can´t retrieve privilegies.
That happen to me when I imported a site, because this field on the **wp**_options table
     **oldprefix**_user_roles (usually **wp**_user_roles)
should be renamed 
     **newprefix**_user_roles

Hope is clear, I think this will resolve your problem.